# Why is setExact() Alarm manager method ignoring my interval time?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm to show a Toast message in my app after 10 seconds but for any reason this message shows after 6 seconds and it is ignoring the time I pass to te setExact method:

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, processTimerReceiver.class);            
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
mgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10000, pi);
```

This is my Receiver class:

```
public class processTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Receiver in my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".processTimerReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="processTimerReceiver" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

what am I doing wrong?

I am testing on a Android 8.0 Oreo device.

Comment: Every 6 seconds? Where are you setting this alarm to start ? Can you post a bit for that?

Comment: Oops! I meant after 6 seconds. The alarm is set inside onclick method

Comment: I think you need to change the milliseconds time and check it again. I'm still not sure about why it's finishing after 6 seconds (maybe layout is delaying the performance but it's rare). The milliseconds you mentioned here would be the unix timestamp+10000 ms to work the alarm correctly. You're setting it to 10000 which is causing alarm to finish as soon as it's getting the hit on  onclick method.
And if it still doesn't work then please post your onclick method from where alarm is getting called.

Comment: You are correct I just added this `mgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pi);` and now it works

Comment: Great! Happy coding :)

Comment: @Swr7der thanks a lot